# Computer sluggish while running speed test

Tags: performance, desktop-computer

Recently my computer has become very sluggish when running internet speed tests (the PC itself, not the internet speed).

I've also noticed this when downloading stuff sometimes, I thought it may be the speed on my hard drive, but I tried different drives including an SSD (Samsung EVO 850, ~520 Mbps write speed).

It doesn't always happen when downloading, but always does when running speed tests (on speedtest.net and the rogers speed test).

Any ideas?

PS: Running windows 7 x64, i5-2500, 8GB RAM. SSD OS drive.

Comment: Troubleshooting performance issues requires much more than a few assumptions.  What is your CPU, memory, and disk drive usage before and during the test?

Comment: it was 30-50% usage without anything, up to 70% when running the test. I restarted the WMI service and it temporarily brought it down to ~15-20% idle and ~50% running the tests, but when up again after a few minutes.

Comment: Then you'll need to look more closely at the resource monitor to see what causes that usage.

Comment: If the computer is getting slower, perhaps it would be time for a good cleanup like removing unneeded programs, running spyware scans, and defragmenting.

Comment: your system should not be running at 30-50% when it is idle. Also, how much free ram do you have, and how much disk IO activity is there?